# Why is TreeMap reset after every reduce method?

Tags: hadoop

In my `reduce` method, I want to operate with the `TreeMap` variable `reduceMap` to aggregate the incoming key values. However, this map loses it's state with every `reduce` method call. Subsequently Hadoop prints only the very last value (plus the test values I added) that is put into the TreeMap. Why is that? It does work as I intend it in my `map` method.

```
public static class TopReducer extends
            Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable> {

        private TreeMap<Text, Integer> reducedMap = new TreeMap<Text, Integer>();

        @Override
        public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values,
                Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

            int sum = 0;
            String strValues = "";
            for (IntWritable value : values) {
                sum += value.get();
                strValues += value.get() + ", ";
            }
            System.out.println("Map size Before: " +reducedMap);
            Integer val = sum;
            if (reducedMap.containsKey(key))
                val += reducedMap.get(key);
            // Only add, if value is of top 30.
            reducedMap.put(key, val);
            System.out.println("Map size After: " +reducedMap);
            reducedMap.put(new Text("test"), 77777);

            System.out.println("REDUCER: rcv: (" + key + "), " + "(" + sum
                    + "), (" + strValues + "):: new (" + val + ")");
        }

        /**
         * Flush top 30 context to the next phase.
         */
        @Override
        protected void cleanup(Context context) throws IOException,
                InterruptedException {
            System.out.println("-----FLUSHING TOP " + TOP_N
                    + " MAPPING RESULTS-------");
            System.out.println("MapSize: " + reducedMap);
            int i = 0;
            for (Entry<Text, Integer> entry : entriesSortedByValues(reducedMap)) {
                System.out.println("key " + entry.getKey() + ", value "
                        + entry.getValue());
                context.write(entry.getKey(), new IntWritable(entry.getValue()));

                if (i >= TOP_N)
                    break;
                else
                    i++;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hadoop re-uses object references for efficiency purposes - so when you call `reducedMap.put(key, val)` the key value will match a key already in the map (because Hadoop had just replaced the contents of your key object, not given you a new reference to a new object with new contents). It's effectively the same as calling the following:

```
Text key = new Text("x");
reducedMap.put(key, val); // map will be of size 1
key.set("y");
reducedMap.put(key, val); // map will still be of size 1
                          // as it will be comparing key to the itself
                          // and just updating the mapped value val
```

You need to make a deep copy of your key before putting it into the map:

```
reducedMap.put(new Text(key), val)
```